# Wrap function with the same name as a builtin

Tags: c++, cython

I'm trying to wrap a C++ class with the following definition

```
cdef extern from "MyClass":
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
        MyClass() except +
        int exec()
```

Compiling throws an "Empty declarator" error on the last line, which I guess is because the function is named as a builtin. Using other builtin functions has the same results.

How would I wrap this function? It's not possible for me to change the function name since it's part of a compiled library.

I tried deleting `'__builtins__'` from `globals()` but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See docs [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#resolving-naming-conflicts-c-name-specifications) - you can provide an alias for naming conflicts

```
cdef extern from 'MyClass.h':
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
        MyClass()
        int my_exec "exec" ()
```